# Xcode Persistent Tab Bar Navigation

Tags: ios, navigation, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

So I'm building an app where I need a persistent tab bar navigation at the bottom of the screen, exactly like how the Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn and Instagram iOS apps do. Now whilst I can use a TabBarController and link the main pages of the app, I need the TabBar to be present on every page and not just the first page of each section.

I tried creating a UITabBar class and importing it into one of my ViewControllerClasses so that I don't have to add a TabBar on every single view. But when I add this UITabBar class as a subview of the ViewController I can't seem to change any of it's properties such as background colour.

Can anyone suggest what might be wrong or suggest any better methods of approaching a persistent tab bar navigation on every page of the app?

Comment: are you using a tab bar controller?

Comment: Not yet I was just using a UITabBar class and importing that into my ViewController class programmatically as well as importing the UITabBar class. But the tab bar was just black and I couldn't change any of the colours.

Comment: and your view controller isn't acting as a container for all the others, so you have multiple tab bars defined in the app?

Comment: No it's not. My plan was to create a single tab bar class, which had all of the colours, images and methods (to send the user to various views) inside it. Then I wanted to import that tab bar class into certain ViewControllerClasses as a persistent navigation. In the same way that the Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn and Instagram iOS apps do.

Comment: don't do that, use a container view controller (your own or a tab bar controller) to manage it